# Using secret environment variables with angular 4+ and nodejs

Tags: angular, github, environment-variables

I have an Angular 4 app with a node backend. I'm using social logins like facebook and linkedin which requires the angular2-social-logins npm package. To use this package I have to use my client IDs in my app module. How can keep these variables a secret and not push the code when pushing to GitHub?

Here's my app.module

```
let providers = {
  "google": {
    "clientId": environment.providers.google.clientId
  },
  "linkedin": {
    "clientId": environment.providers.linkedin.clientId
  },
  "facebook": {
    "clientId": environment.providers.facebook.clientId,
    "apiVersion": environment.providers.facebook.apiVersion
  }
};



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LandingPageComponent,
    NavComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FacebookModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    Angular2SocialLoginModule

  ],
  providers: [
    UserService,
    UiService,


  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}

Angular2SocialLoginModule.loadProvidersScripts(providers);
```

The clientIds are currently stored in environment/environment.ts.

I dont want these seen when I push to github.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You need to pay for a private repository in order to hide it from everyone otherwise it will be "open-source"

Answer (score 0):

You could always add your environment files to a .gitignore file so they are not pushed up to git. https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

Comment: But then how would I access those vars in production. I use heroku for deployment.

Comment: yeah if you don't store the env files in the repo. You'll need some way to generate/push the env file to the server. I'm not familiar with heroku so I'm not sure what the best route is.